# ROR new action error Couldn't find Post with ID=nexttwentyfive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, conditional-statements

I am getting an error where it thinks my action is post id?

URL http://localhost:3000/posts/nexttwentyfive?lastid=1

```
def nexttwentyfive
  @posts = Post.find(:all, :order => "date", :limit => 25, :conditions => ["id=? AND created_at > ?", Time.now, params[:lastid]])

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.xml  { render :xml => @post } 
   format.json { render :json => @post }
 end
end 

map.resources :posts, :collection => { :nexttwentyfive => :get  }
```

Comment: Did you restart your server? What does `rake routes | grep "next"` output?

Comment: @nathanvda `map.resources` is Rails2 routing syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow @macarthy 's advice and restart the server/check routes.

The error you're getting show the nexttwentyfive route is not recognized as the collection and it's being handled as /posts/:id